# Production ENV file with docker/build-push-action and GitHub Actions

Tags: docker, environment-variables, github-actions, dockerhub, dotenv

I have the following `docker/build-push-action` job that runs in my GitHub actions when a release tag is created.

```
jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      -
        name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      -
        name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      -
        name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1 
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_TOKEN }}
      -
        name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: user/repo:latest
      -
        name: Image digest
        run: echo ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.digest }}
```

In my `Dockerfile` I have a task that takes `.env.production` and makes it `.env`.

```
COPY .env.production .env
```

This obviously fails because .env.production is not included in Git.

My question is, how do I get a similar thing to happen in my GitHub actions? I thought about creating the env file before `Build and push` but I *think* that task pulls from main in a docker container so won't actually see my created file? Or if anything overwrite it.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you come up with a good solution for this? Facing exactly the same issue. My best idea is to just create another yml that runs before with the secret env values stored in GitHub secrets.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I came up with.

Dockerfile

```
...
ARG ARG_ENV_SECRET
ARG ARG_ENV_SECRET_1
COPY ./env-script.sh ./
RUN ./env-script.sh
...
```

env-script.sh This script creates the .env FILE

```
#!/bin/sh

touch .env
{
  printf "ENV_SECRET=%sENV_SECRET_1=%s" "$ARG_ENV_SECRET" "ARG_ENV_SECRET_1"
} >> .env
```

docker-action.yml

```
...

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Build, tag, and push the image to Amazon ECR
        id: build-image
        env:
          ENV_SECRET: ${{ secrets.ENV_SECRET }} #naming used below
          ENV_SECRET_1: ${{ secrets.ENV_SECRET_1 }}
        run: |
          docker \ 
           --build-arg ARG_ENV_SECRET=$ENV_SECRET #name declared above
           --build-arg ARG_ENV_SECRET_1=$ENV_SECRET_1
          build .
...
```

I'm pretty sure this is not the best route but it's worked for us since we use a third party to run our AWS services. A better approach would be to use AWS secrets when starting the instance. You can read more about it [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-data-security-container-task/).